# Number of shortest paths between two nodes in undirected unweighted graph

Tags: search-algorithms, shortest-path, dijkstras-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to devise a $O(|V| + |E|)$ algorithm to calculate number of shortest paths between $s$ and $f$ on a undirected, unweighted graph. Can someone please check my pseudo-code? Also, isn't

$O(|V| + |E|) + O(|V| + |E|)$ = $O(|V| + |E|)$?
[image]

Comment: We typically don't check answers. We can help you if you have any specific doubts.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm trying to self learn and I didn't find this coding problem online so I'm unable to verify if my solution is fine. For recursive solutions, I struggle to show their correctness

Comment: This is **not** a coding problem, but rather its an algorithmic problem. The best way to verify your answer is to try to prove it (mathematically). The proof should be similar to that of BFS.

Comment: A $O(|V|+|E|)$ algorithm doesn't mean much. The big-oh notation denotes a set of functions. You probably meant A an algorithm with time complexity of $O(|V|+|E|)$.